# Handlebars compile operation not permitted

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, appharbor

I'm trying to get Handlebars pre-compilation working on AppHarbor. We are following the instructions [here](http://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html) which works on all out build machines except for AppHarbor. Here's the error log:

```
   CompileHandlebarsTemplates:
     Compiling Handlebars template files
     Executing handlebars  --output "templates.js" --min "D:\temp\iglbataj.o25\input\comp-prod-5d066abce08570e82575d1a1c877bd5c94d27b1c\WebApp\Templates"
     node "D:\temp\iglbataj.o25\input\comp-prod-5d066abce08570e82575d1a1c877bd5c94d27b1c\WebApp\Build\npm\node_modules\handlebars\bin\handlebars"  --output "templates.js" --min "D:\temp\iglbataj.o25\input\comp-prod-5d066abce08570e82575d1a1c877bd5c94d27b1c\WebApp\Templates"

     fs.js:679
       return binding.lstat(pathModule._makeLong(path));
                      ^
 5>EXEC : error : EPERM, operation not permitted 'D:\temp' [D:\temp\iglbataj.o25\input\comp-prod-5d066abce08570e82575d1a1c877bd5c94d27b1c\WebApp\WebApp.csproj]
         at Object.fs.lstatSync (fs.js:679:18)
         at Object.realpathSync (fs.js:1265:21)
         at tryFile (module.js:142:15)
         at Function.Module._findPath (module.js:181:18)
         at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:25)
         at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
         at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
         at startup (node.js:119:16)
         at node.js:901:3
```

We have checked in the node.js handlebars module. Tried invoking it using node.exe installed on AppHarbor as well as checking in both x64 and x86 versions of node.exe. None of them works. Tried replicating really long paths locally to see if the problem is that still builds locally with long paths. Even tried outputting to default output instead of a file to no avail. At this point I am stuck on this issue. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

this is a permission problem.

Probably that your node process don't have the right permission to read the files or write in the destination folder.

You could force it with `sudo`, but that's no really a solution. So check the permission and make sure the node process has access to writing and reading on the related directory/files.

You can google `chmod` and `chown` for instruction on how to change permissions. (I can't help you any further without more detail on your system architecture)

Comment: AppHarbor runs on Windows. It doesn't seem to be read or write permission because during my build process I can read and write to those paths without nodejs. I also tried running just `node handlebars` without giving any arguments so that it only shows help but I still get the same error. The handlebars module is checked in and the path is correct otherwise I would get `Cannot find module`

Comment: Sorry I overlooked by giving Unix commands. Although, using Windows don't mean your won't have misconfiguration in permission (and that is still your issue). Permissions issues are particularly true when using IIS or Azure. So make sure the user associated with your build process have write access to the destination directory.

Comment: My issue looks like to be similar to the one mentioned [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3977) but I don't have any symlinks.

Comment: For me, handlerbars looks for "npm" on my path which is C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm. iis runs under "Network Service". So you must give Network Service read perm on MyUserName dir and write on the npm dir, I think (I applied write on my entire user dir and it worked). I don't really like doing this. You can test the handlebar command under network service account by doing this: psexec -u "nt authority\network service" cmd.exe (psexec from sysinternals). The code is in HandlebarsBundleTransform.cs PrecompileTemplate. A breakpoint there will give you a sample command line.